# Optional tags within XML document?

Tags: java, xml

I'm working on a missile-combat oriented game written in java that reads missile types with settings from an XML document. Each missile has many different parameters that can clog up the XML sometimes and make it hard to handle each missile type. What I am wondering is if it would be possible to code the XML parsing section of the code so that I can put in only the options that will be different from a default value. For example, one of the parameters is "nuclear," which can be true or false to indicate a nuclear missile. Would it be possible to write the code so that if  is not present, it defaults to "false?"

Here is a missile type in the XML:

````
<MissileType ID="1" Name="Tomahawk">
  <AssetID>15</AssetID>
  <Purchasable>true</Purchasable>
  <SpeedIndex>1</SpeedIndex>
  <MissileCost>550</MissileCost>
  <BlastRadiusIndex>2</BlastRadiusIndex>
  <RangeIndex>3</RangeIndex>
  <MaxDamageIndex>3</MaxDamageIndex>
  <Nuclear>false</Nuclear>
  <Tracking>true</Tracking>
  <ECM>true</ECM>
</MissileType>```
````

Here is the code that parses the missile type:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ndeMissileTypes.getLength(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Element ndeMissileType = (Element)ndeMissileTypes.item(i);
                byte cID = GetByteAttribute(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.ID);
                String strName = GetStringAttribute(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.NAME);
                int lAssetID = GetIntElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.ASSET_ID);
                boolean bPurchasable = GetBooleanElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.PURCHASABLE);
                byte cSpeedIndex = GetByteElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.SPEED_INDEX);
                int cMissileCost = GetIntElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.MISSILE_COST); 
                byte cBlastRadiusIndex = GetByteElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.BLAST_RADIUS_INDEX);
                byte cRangeIndex = GetByteElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.RANGE_INDEX);
                byte cMaxDamageIndex = GetByteElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.MAX_DAMAGE_INDEX);
                boolean bNuclear = GetBooleanElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.NUCLEAR);
                boolean bTracking = GetBooleanElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.TRACKING);
                boolean bECM = GetBooleanElement(ndeMissileType, XMLDefs.ECM);
                                                                                                                                         
                config.AddMissileType(cID, new MissileType(cID, bPurchasable, strName, lAssetID, bNuclear, bTracking, bECM, cSpeedIndex, cMissileCost, cRangeIndex, cBlastRadiusIndex, cMaxDamageIndex));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                listener.LoadError(String.format("Error loading missile type at index %d: %s.", i, ex.getMessage()));
            }
        }
```

I would like it so that I can leave out lines from `<MissileType>` and have it return a default value for that position. For example, have a missile type that looks like this:

```
<MissileType ID="1" Name="Tomahawk">
  <AssetID>15</AssetID>
  <Purchasable>true</Purchasable>
  <SpeedIndex>1</SpeedIndex>
  <MissileCost>550</MissileCost>
  <BlastRadiusIndex>2</BlastRadiusIndex>
  <RangeIndex>3</RangeIndex>
  <MaxDamageIndex>3</MaxDamageIndex>
</MissileType>
```

Which would return false for the missing boolean values at the end, essentially allowing me to only input the tags that are relevant to this particular missile type.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. I can't see what your problem is. Just write

```
boolean bPurchasable = getBooleanElement(ndeMissileType,  XMLDefs.PURCHASABLE, false);
```

where the 3-argument method is defined as

```
public boolean getBooleanElement(Element parent, QName name, boolean default) {
  return parent.hasChild(name) ? GetBooleanElement(parent, name) : default
}
```

(Treat this as pseudo-code, because I don't know what API you are actually using. Note Java method names conventionally use an initial lower-case letter.)

Comment: Thank you VERY much! I did not know this was possible. I'm a java novice. Much appreciated.